# Error when trying to split Datetime Field

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/juanpex/django-model-report) reporting tool and I noticed that in their example they are using something like this

```
'date__year',
'date__month',
'date__day',
```

for a **datetime** field named *date*.

I liked the idea and I prefer it from using another field for my own model that will hold the year and another one for the month etc.

The thing is that this does not work for me as I get

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to'
```

Has something changed in the latest versions of django, and can I do something to fix this and avoid using multiple fields?

**EDIT**

This is the full error

```
Internal Server Error: /timers-by-user-report/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\model_report\views.py", line 34, in report
    report = report_class(request=request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\model_report\report.py", line 259, in __init__
    base_model = pre_field.rel.to
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to'
```

[image]

As I said it happens only if I try something similar to the example where I try to access __year from a datetime object

```
fields = [
        'timer_user__user_name',
        'timer_enterTime',
        'timer_enterTime__month',
    ]
```

Comment: Show full exception and corresponding line please.

Comment: @ReutSharabani hope the edit helps.

Comment: **Exception Location: ...\model_report\report.py in \_\_init__, line 259.** Where's that code? Not in your question.

Comment: I know, but that is not my code, it comes from the package I installed and linked to the question. That why I didnt add that part hoping that someone else had encountered the same issue and knows the reason.

Comment: Print your model and view code.

Comment: @RajeshKaushik no this is not how this module works, or all the other reporting tools for Django as far as I have seen. You create a `reports.py` file and that is used for creating the report. You dont write anything else.

Comment: I tried to experiment with django too for some time. I had no idea that there existed such reporting tools but if this works it could be quite interesting.